# Displaying an AWS S3 Object/Image on Angular Frontend

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I try to **display an image** I get **from s3 via aws-sdk** in my Angular frontend.
Getting my credentials via Cognito works fine.
However I have some trouble with **connecting the response from `getObject` to my image-source tag**. `<img src="image" />`

Answer (score 1):

After some research I came up with the following solution using an **object url**.

1. creating a new Blob from response data with adding the MIME Type.
2. create an object URL
3. sanitize the the object URL with DomSanitizer to create a safe URL
4. bind the safe URL to img-tag `<img src="image" />`

```
s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error fetching S3 object:', err);
        } else {

            var blobObj = new Blob([data.Body! as Uint8Array], { type: "image/jpg" });
            
            var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blobObj);
            image.next(this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL));
        }
    });
```